# Finding Alpha Rank on Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on an excel-based database of equipment for an invoiced project. Each unique project will have it's own workbook, but I'm trying to build a template workbook to limit how much manual work goes into each project's invoicing. Each piece of equipment has a Model, Serial, and allowable Address range.

**Models** - Let's say we have three: Grey_Box, Blue_Box, and Pink_Box, and that for an example project we have three of each of these boxes, for a total of nine boxes in our database.

**Serials** - Every box (regardless of model) has a unique serial number.

**Addresses** - Each model has an allowable address range. For example, a Grey_Box will be addressed between 800 and 899, starting with 800 and increasing by 1 for each unique box of that model type.

What I'm struggling with is how to find the alphanumeric rank of each box within it's model type to dynamically assign the Address. Any given project can have hundreds to thousands of boxes, and assigning these by hand is a chore that I feel can easily be automated by adding the rank to the starting address.

To Summmarize the example:

- Box Name | Serial | Starting Address
- Grey_Box | AM04 | 0800
- Grey_Box | TI18 | 0800
- Grey_Box | GH34 | 0800
- Blue_Box | XJ94 | 1000
- Blue_Box | BC01 | 1000
- Blue_Box | JK42 | 1000
- Pink_Box | HI38 | 2400
- Pink_Box | CD22 | 2400
- Pink_Box | LQ00 | 2400

I'd love to find a way to add a formula that adds the Rank to the Starting Address. For example, AM04 would be 800, GH34 would be 801, and TI18 would be 802.

I have found that I'm able to return the alphabetical rank of the Serial Numbers with "=COUNTIF([SERIAL], "<="&[@SERIAL])" in my table. This ranks them cross-model though, and that doesn't quite get me there. I feel like I'm missing a piece of knowledge on what excel can **do** and that's what's keeping me from finding the solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a google search for [excel alphabetic rank](https://www.google.ca/search?q=excel+alphabetic+rank&rlz=1C1CHZL_enCA733CA733&oq=excel+alphabetic+rank&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.2726j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: btw, Gray_Box <> Grey_Box .

Comment: Good catch on Gray vs Grey - that was a poor color choice on my part. I have a varied client list and some vary on which they prefer! Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've interpreted your ask correctly I think you might be after a COUNTIFS formula. I noticed you were using a table so I have used that syntax:

`=COUNTIFS([Box],[@Box],[Serial],"<"&[@Serial])+[@[Starting Address]]`

Which results in this output:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. Succinct, Discernible, and Fast - thank you! I knew I was missing a piece and Countif**S** was clearly it!

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=COUNTIFS([Box Name], [@[Box Name]], [Serial], "<="&[@Serial])+VLOOKUP([@[Box Name]], F$4:G$6, 2, FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I marked maxhob17's response as the answer, but this works too. I have a separate tab in the workbook that has a pre-defined table of details for each model, and had already figured the vlookup out to get the starting address for the model. This answer is essentially how I will implement it, but I didn't want to include more information that may have obfuscated an answer to the problem at hand. Thank you!